# Why does connecting media to an already running audiomixer or a compositor cause an increased persistent delay?

Tags: gstreamer

I've noticed that when an `audiomixer` or a `compositor` (GstAggregator elements) that is already processing buffers receives a new connection, there is a drift of 80 ms or so.

Ex.

1. Media connected to audiomixer / compositor.
2. Glass-to-glass latency is ~170 ms.
3. Connect another media stream.
4. Glass-to-glass latency is ~250 ms.

It might be how im connecting the new stream to the GstAggregator's. I noticed a prop called `ignore-inactive-pads` that my old version of GStreamer doesn't have access to. So I instead probe the source element for a downstream buffer and only connect it when that callback fires.

I assume whatever internal clock state is stored by the GstAggregator's drifts ahead when a new media stream is connected (i.e. a higher PTS is assigned).

Does anyone have experience with this?